# How to set a variable in Postgress PGadmin 4 editor?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set a variable in (Postgress) pgAdmin editor. Sql script is working without variable. But I want to test it with a variable.

```
DECLARE seller_id integer := 100;
        created_at time := now();
select seller_profiles.user_id,seller_profiles.business_name,seller_profiles.status, buyer_profiles.first_name, images.image_url, buyer_profiles.last_name,  user_details.email from seller_profiles 
inner join user_details on user_details.user_id = seller_profiles.user_id
left join address_books on address_books.id = seller_profiles.address_book_id
left join phone_numbers on phone_numbers.id = seller_profiles.phone_number_id
inner join buyer_profiles on buyer_profiles.user_id = seller_profiles.user_id
left join images on images.id = seller_profiles.business_logo_id
where seller_profiles.user_id = seller_id
```

However, I get the following error when run:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "integer"
LINE 1: DECLARE seller_id integer := 100;
                          ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 19
```

Any help ?

Comment: You cannot use variables in SQL in Postgres (with a single "s", BTW). That can only be done in PL/pgSQL.

Comment: Hmm, never expected that.